# enumerate through all substrings of an nsstring with a fixed length in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I'm trying to write a method that generates all substrings of a given NSString with a fixed length, but I'm getting stuck. Here's the idea of what I want:

```
-(int)countGoodSubstringsOfString:(NSString*)str ofLength:(int)len {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (NSString *substr substring of str of length len) {
        if ([self isGoodSubstring:substr ofString:str])
            cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

By substring, I mean all possible combinations of `len` characters from `str`. If `str = @"ABCDE"` and `len = 4`, then I need to get 5 substrings: `@"ABCD", @"ABCE", @"ABDE", @"ACDE", @"BCDE"`.

If `len` were fixed, then I could just write nested `for` loops to get all the substrings like this

```
NSString *substr = @"";
for (int i=0; i<str.length-len+1; ++i) {
    substr = [substr stringByAppendingString:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)]];
    for (int j=i+1; j<str.length-len+2; ++j) {
        substr = [substr stringByAppendingString:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j,1)]];
        ...
            for(int k=j+1; k<str.length; ++k) {
                substr = [substr stringByAppendingString:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(k,1)]];
                if ([self isGoodSubstring:substr ofString:str])
                    cnt++;
```

But since `len` is part of the input, I can't know it in advance. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Those are not substrings. And there are more than 5 of the kind of strings you are looking for. What you need is Permutation(5,4) number of strings from str.

Comment: @MadhavanRP Actually, I need to keep them in the same order as they appear in the str.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html in addition to what MadhavanRP wrote.

Comment: @mit3z I mean "substring" in the sense of "subsequence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I finally managed to find the solution. It uses same ideas as yours, but it's recursive, so you don't have to know the length.

```
-(int)countGoodSubstringsOfString:(NSString*)str ofLength:(int)len recStr:(NSString *)recStr from:(int)from{
  /// C(str.length, str.length-len)
  if (!recStr) {
    recStr = @"";
  }
  if ([recStr length]==len) {
    if ([self isGoodSubstring:substr ofString:str])
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int i=from; i<=str.length-len+[recStr length]; i++) {
    NSString *substr = [recStr stringByAppendingString:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
    cnt += [self countGoodSubstringsOfString:str ofLength:len recStr:substr from:i+1];
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

Initial call should look something like this:

```
int cnt = [self countGoodSubstringsOfString:@"ABCDEF" ofLength:4 recStr:nil from:0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need all possible substrings, even the ones that are not consecutive. I'll add an example to clarify.

Comment: I understand. I updated the solution, from my tests it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely clear what are you trying to do, but if you want to get all substrings of string separated by @" " of a given length - then it looks like this:

```
NSString *str = @"length string blah lskdnflskdls lkjbfe lkfngj";
int length = 6;
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.length = %d", length];
NSArray *arr = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
NSLog(@"filtered substrings: %@", arr);
```

output looks like this:

```
filtered substrings: (
    length,
    string,
    lkjbfe,
    lkfngj
)
```

Comment: I have no idea what this does. Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not at all what I'm after. I need all possible combinations of `len` characters from `str`, like in the example I just added.